Pre-2010 sci-fi love story about mankind being enslaved by robots where humans don't have names
I can't remember the name of  a movie about a science fiction lovestory.
The things i can remember are:

the movie cover is mostly white and you can see a person with white clothes and a bald head who is sitting.
the title of the movie could be a number.
the movie is about mankind which is enslaved by robots. 
The humans don't have names anymore just numbers and everybody has a bald head.
the movie was released before 2010.

Would be great if you guys can help me:)

George Lucas' first film, THX 1138, fits most of what you describe:

There is a movie poster which is mostly white with bald man sitting down
The title of the movie contains a number
Emotions are suppressed making everyone robot-like
Everyone is shaved and has an identifying designation like THX 1138
It's from 1971, which is pre-2010


And the director's cut was released in 2004, which makes it seem more contemporary.
